# error sending photoMessage in balebot

Tags: bale-messenger

I've tried to send a photoMessage.Socket disconnect while trying to send photo/file message with empty error in [promise catch callback]
I dont know why?How can i fix it?

```
[2018-05-07 13:31:40.432] [TRACE] [default] - Sending on socket: {"$type":"Request","id":"3","service":"messaging","body":{"$type":"SendMessage","peer":{"$type":"User","id":XXX,"accessHash":"YYY"},"randomId":"796200377717532288","message":{"$type":"Document","fileId":"-5218264593238523391","accessHash":6687875,"fileSize":"157727","name":"871073.jpg","mimeType":"image/jpg","thumb":{},"ext":{"$type":"Photo"},"caption":{"$type":"Text","text":"test"},"checkSum":"checkSum","algorithm":"algorithm","fileStorageVersion":1}}}
[2018-05-07 13:31:40.435] [TRACE] [default] - send callback: err: undefined
[2018-05-07 13:31:43.221] [INFO] [default] - Connecting...
[2018-05-07 13:31:43.913] [INFO] [default] - Socket Connected!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s necessary to specify the thumbnail,width and height in photoMessage.